# PyQt: Is it possible to drag/drop QWidgets in a QGridLayout to rearrange them?

Tags: pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qwidget, qgridlayout

I am looking for a way to create a grid of graphs that can be dragged/dropped to rearrange the order. My first try was using QDockWidgets as they allow for drag/drop, however they were limited in a lot of other ways. Would it be possible to implement this function in a QGridLayout?

For now I have a QGridLayout with 3x3 matplotlib widgets.

Here is an example of the desired layout outcome.

[image]

Sample code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import random

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QWidget, QDialog, QApplication, QFrame

class IndicSelectWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(IndicSelectWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(1000, 800)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QWidget()
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        for i in range(3):
             for j in range(3):
                 self.Frame = QFrame(self)
                 self.Frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
                 self.Frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Raised)
                 self.Frame.setLineWidth(2)
                 self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.Frame)

                 self.figure = Figure()  # a figure to plot on
                 self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
                 self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)  # create an axis
                 data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]
                 self.ax.plot(data, '*-')  # plot data
                 self.canvas.draw()  # refresh canvas

                 self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

                 Box = QVBoxLayout()

                 Box.addWidget(self.Frame)

                 self.gridLayout.addLayout(Box, i, j)
                 self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(i % 3, 1)
                 self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(j, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = IndicSelectWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an implementation that will swap the positions of the items involved in a drag/drop. The 3 main steps are:

(1) Reimplement `mousePressEvent` to get the index of the `LayoutItem` based on mouse coordinates.

(2) Reimplement `mouseMoveEvent` to set up a `QDrag` of the FigureCanvas.

(3) Reimplement `dropEvent` to swap the target items in the layout.

Since the matplotlib widgets absorb mouse events you also need to reimplement `eventFilter` to detect them.

```
import sys, random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class IndicSelectWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(IndicSelectWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(1000, 800)

        self.target = None
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QWidget()
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                self.Frame = QFrame(self)
                self.Frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
                self.Frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Panel | QFrame.Raised)
                self.Frame.setLineWidth(2)
                self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.Frame)

                self.figure = Figure()  # a figure to plot on
                self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
                self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)  # create an axis
                data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]
                self.ax.plot(data, '*-')  # plot data
                self.canvas.draw()  # refresh canvas
                self.canvas.installEventFilter(self)

                self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

                Box = QVBoxLayout()

                Box.addWidget(self.Frame)

                self.gridLayout.addLayout(Box, i, j)
                self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(i % 3, 1)
                self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(j, 1)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.mousePressEvent(event)
        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            self.mouseMoveEvent(event)
        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            self.mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        return super().eventFilter(watched, event)

    def get_index(self, pos):
        for i in range(self.gridLayout.count()):
            if self.gridLayout.itemAt(i).geometry().contains(pos) and i != self.target:
                return i

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.target = self.get_index(event.windowPos().toPoint())
        else:
            self.target = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton and self.target is not None:
            drag = QDrag(self.gridLayout.itemAt(self.target))
            pix = self.gridLayout.itemAt(self.target).itemAt(0).widget().grab()
            mimedata = QMimeData()
            mimedata.setImageData(pix)
            drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
            drag.setPixmap(pix)
            drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
            drag.exec_()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.target = None

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if not event.source().geometry().contains(event.pos()):
            source = self.get_index(event.pos())
            if source is None:
                return

            i, j = max(self.target, source), min(self.target, source)
            p1, p2 = self.gridLayout.getItemPosition(i), self.gridLayout.getItemPosition(j)

            self.gridLayout.addItem(self.gridLayout.takeAt(i), *p2)
            self.gridLayout.addItem(self.gridLayout.takeAt(j), *p1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = IndicSelectWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks @alec! Brilliant solution. Based on your code I will try to implement a way so the widgets push each other instead of swapping.

Comment: @FrederikPetri Happy to help! I think it should be possible with [setDropAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdropevent.html#setDropAction) to Qt.MoveAction. And some concepts from the [Flow Layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the concepts you mentioned.

Comment: @alec it would be good to add a `drag.setPixmap()` with the same image, so that the user knows that it's moving it. And, while you're at that, also a `drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())` would be nice :-)